# Submitting html form in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my first.php page html part. I have a form including a div and a submit button. I want when button clicked, open a new page (second.php) and display contents of div(id=orderList)

```
<form id="orderForm" action="second.php">
          <div class="col-md-5" id="orderList">
               <h3 align="center">Sipariş Listesi</h3>
          </div>  
          <div>
               <button type="submit" id="firstConfirmButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Onayla</button>
          </div>
</form>
```

This is javascript part;

```
 $("#orderForm").submit(function() {

    var content = $('#orderList').html();

    console.log(content); //(no problem everything is ok)

    $('#confirmForm').val(content);

    var content2 = $('#confirmForm').html();
    console.log(content2); //(it is null)

});
```

And this is second.php where I want to display the contents in the div(id=confirmForm)

```
<html>
   <head>    

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <META name=viewport content="width=1024, initial-scale=1">
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-language" CONTENT="tr">

    <link href="shift.css" rel="stylesheet">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="product.css">

 </head>

  <body>

    <div id="confirmForm">  </div> 

  </body>

</html>
```

It doesn't work, what should I change?

Comment: Google `ajax` with `jquery` if you want the contents of the second page to be displayed on the current page you are submitting the form using an asynchronous request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$('#confirmForm')` is not an input item you cant access it using `$('#confirmForm').val()`;

your Form is missing `method` attribute, add `POST` in method by default its `GET`

```
<form id="orderForm" method="post" action="second.php">
```

Add a `<textarea>` in `first.php` inside `orderForm` to hold the content of `#ordelist` using jquery and in second page you can get it using `$_POST['confirmForm']`;

```
<textarea name="confirmForm" id="confirmForm" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

in second page you do this

```
<div id="confirmForm"> <?php echo $_POST['confirmForm'] ?> </div>
```

Comment: I can see the text area filled with content, no problem thnks for solution. But second.php is blank? var_dump($_POST['confirmForm']); is null

Comment: just use `print_r($_POST);` on top of second page to see what it gives you. you must get the content from form submission, and then use key as i shown you above

Comment: print_r($_POST); result is Array ( )

Comment: updated form method to post  `<form id="orderForm" method="post" action="second.php">` that will do it

Comment: yepp, it is solved. Thanks, I forgot to put textarea in orderForm.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to put the content in #confirmForm, which isn't present in the first file.

There is no need for JavaScript here. Grab the content of the div using $_['post']

Comment: How should I use  $_['post'], in first.php or second.php?

Comment: I changed it but still null

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working :

**first.php**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<form id="orderForm" action="second.php">
          <div class="col-md-5" id="orderList">
               <textarea name="confirmForm" id="confirmForm" cols="30" rows="10">Sipari Listesi</textarea>
          </div>  
          <div>
               <button type="submit" id="firstConfirmButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Onayla</button>
          </div>
</form>
</html>
```

**second.php**

```
<html>
  <body>

<?php 
  echo $_REQUEST[confirmForm];
?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Saqueib said, I think you'll need to make a jQuery change too. I think you're looking for the html() method, not val() because it looks like you're trying to change the displayed HTML, right?

Comment: I tried that but it denied me twice. Wasn't sure why though.